# Get-ComplianceSearch / Get-ComplianceSearchAction download the search and export statistics file via powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to download the [Search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-keyword-statistics-for-content-search-results-9701a024-c52e-43f0-b545-9a53478aec04) and Export statistics from office 365 compliance search.

I am able to export the results using below query. But I need the statistics. How can I do that?

```
Get-ComplianceSearchAction -Identity "Sam_PS_Search2_Preview" | Select Results | Export-Csv c:\tempz\results.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I just needed the same solution as the op.  Here's what I did.

```
$Results = (Get-ComplianceSearchAction 'searchName_Preview' -Details).Results -replace '{', "Location,Sender,Subject,Type,Size,ReceivedTime,DataLink`r`n" -replace '}' -replace 'Location: ' -replace '; Sender: ', ',' -replace '; Subject: ', ',' -replace '; Type: ', ',' -replace '; Size: ', ',' -replace '; Received Time: ', ',' -replace '; Data Link: ', ',' -replace ",`r`n", "`r`n" | Out-File $Home\Desktop\Results.csv
```

After this I had to (in Excel) use the Text to Columns feature on Column A to separate using Comma as the delimiter.  I messed with it for a while to make my pseudo CSV auto-recognize in Excel but didn't get it opted to use Text to Columns rather than waste anymore seconds off my life.

I don't know who they were trying to please when they designed this suite of cmdlets.  The Results field is horrendous. Should be JSON or CSV ready.  I can't think of anyone who would be pleased with the current format, which is one of kind.

Answer (score 0):

If by "statistics" you mean each location in the results, then exporting to CSV isn't going to work because the data isn't in that format. You can, however, use Out-File instead:

$results = Get-ComplianceSearchAction -Identity "Sam_PS_Search2_Preview" | Select Results

$results.Results | Out-File c:\tempz\results.txt

This will get you a file with all of the results, similar to this:

{Location: email@domain.com; Sender: William; Subject: IM/henlo hammy birb; Type: IM; Size: 17880; Received Time: 8/27/2018 1:40:24 PM; Data Link: data/All/FLDRe9310163-848f-472e-9875-298548b21d6e/BATCH0000/MSG7d1a50f4-7c52-4f63-9f36-88555d97f123.eml,
Location: email@domain.com; Sender: Douglas; Subject: IM/henlo hammy birb; Type: IM; Size: 18067; Received Time: 8/27/2018 1:34:30 PM; Data Link: data/All/FLDRe9310163-848f-472e-9875-298548b21d6e/BATCH0000/MSG5a03c111-9b93-4b8f-838c-a72514d4af64.eml,
Location: email@domain.com; Sender: CHRISTOPHER; Subject: IM/Poo Limit Exceeded; Type: IM; Size: 17873; Received Time: 8/31/2018 12:11:00 AM; Data Link: data/All/FLDRe9310163-848f-472e-9875-298548b21d6e/BATCH0000/MSG6eba5094-5ee6-4100-b952-d94e96539530.eml,}